# React Native: Align two TextInputs side by side

Tags: react-native

I am just starting out with React Native and I am developing an app using RN ... I am bit stuck here ... I have a form in one of the app's component that have couple of TextInputs aligned side by side like in the image below

[image]

Here is the code that I have written trying to achieve the above design.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {View, Text, StyleSheet, TextInput, TouchableHighlight} from 'react-native';


export default class AddItems extends Component {
    onAdd() {
        alert('Hello');
    }

    render() {
    return (
        <View style={addItemStyles.wrapper}>
            <View>
                <Text>Item to give cash credit for:</Text>
                <View>
                    <View>
                        <TextInput placeholder="Test" style={{justifyContent: 'flex-start',}} />
                    </View>
                    <View>
                        <TextInput placeholder="Test" style={{justifyContent: 'flex-end',}} />
                    </View>
                </View>
            </View>

        </View>
    );
}
}

const addItemStyles = StyleSheet.create({
    wrapper: {
        padding: 10,
        backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF'
    },
    inputLabels: {
        fontSize: 16,
        color: '#000000',
        marginBottom: 7,
    },
    inputField: {
        backgroundColor: '#EEEEEE',
        padding: 10,
        color: '#505050',
        height: 50
    },
    inputWrapper: {
        paddingBottom: 20,
    },
    saveBtn: {
        backgroundColor: '#003E7D',
        alignItems: 'center',
        padding: 12,
    },
    saveBtnText: {
        color: '#FFFFFF',
        fontSize: 18,
    }


});
```

But instead I am getting the view like this.

[image]

I know this could be a minor thing but as I said above that I am just starting with React Native so you can consider me as a noob ... Thanks in advance for your help. Looking forward to your answers.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

use "flexDirection" in style

```
render() {
    return (
        <View style={addItemStyles.wrapper}>
            <View>
                <Text>Item to give cash credit for:</Text>
                <View style={{flexDirection:"row"}}>
                    <View style={{flex:1}}>
                        <TextInput placeholder="Test" style={{justifyContent: 'flex-start',}} />
                    </View>
                    <View style={{flex:1}}>
                        <TextInput placeholder="Test" style={{justifyContent: 'flex-end',}} />
                    </View>
                </View>
            </View>

        </View>
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answers ... after applying `flexDirection: "row"` should I be giving width to the TextInputs ? Asking this because after your suggestion TextInputs look like this http://prntscr.com/hjtnwk

Comment: @FaISalBLiNK i edited my answer,please try again. use flex :1 to set size is more flexible

Comment: Worked like a charm .. Thanks so much for the help

Comment: I more question for you ... What if I want 4 TextInputs in a row ... do I have to change flex ?

Comment: @FaISalBLiNK: No, just use flex:1 for all TextInputs & justify-content: 'center'.  Those would arrange accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Bilal ... Cheers

Comment: I get "Can't find variable: justifyContent". Help!